# Create basic addon for Archicad 22

Tags: archicad

I install Archicad 22 and Visual Studio 2017. I have Developer API for Archicad. I try to see how it works the example from Archicad Development Kit but when i import from example DC_test is Visual Studio i recive errors.

Can you help me please how to connect Visual Studio example to Archicad? Just bacis .. a line for example.

I want to learn C++ and C#

I want to create an addon like a "eptar reinforcement"
I try to decompile but i cant

Sorry for my bad english.

bogdanproiectare@gmail.com

Thank you very mutch

EDIT:

I want to create an addon as in the image with ARCHICAD, image 3.
Should not there be an open window in the visual studio as in C #? Which can you edit?
Or does Visual Studio somehow connect to Archicad, make changes and they appear in Archicad? In addon?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK5gi.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGmLx.jpg)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hk7c.jpg)

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GDxL.jpg)

[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMX2f.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your question and show us the errors that you are getting?

Comment: I edit. Can you help me please? Just to see a functional example in Archicad, a line or something, that after staying and learning in continuous programming. For you it may seem easy, but for me as a beginner is another world.

Comment: Hi. Sadly I'm not an expert in C# etc either (I'm a ruby on rails person), I'm just very good at helping people to write questions that will get an answer from somebody that is... I recommend that you don't attach images... but actually copy/paste your errors into the question, so that we can copy/paste from them into google if need be.